# Installing Photoshop on Fedora Workstation

Tags: fedora, wine

I currently have a Fedora 23 workstation 64 bit. I installed wine and wanted to install photoshop cs6. When I run the setup.exe `wine setup.exe` the ps6 fails.

anyone got it working?

[image]

Comment: Check the [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607) page for notes on how other people got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider installing a wine helper application such as Crossover Linux or Play on Linux. You can check their supported software list for the version of Photoshop that you are using. Different versions will have varying degrees of support usually with newer versions being less supported.

Other options are using Gimp or running it inside a virtual machine with hardware GPU rendering enabled.

Comment: I had no success with playonlinux either. Gimp is a good program but it's weak. I've been learning it for a week and I don't know if certain features exist. but until now I can't find it on the documentation. I'll just use virtualbox for now. Thanks